# Home assessment - How to make array B from array A C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

Write a program that fills an array A of size 5 filled with random integers in the range 1 to 100 and prints it out (for testing purposes). Write programs that then after creating such a random array, do each of the following:

- Calculate the sum of the elements of A and print it out.
- Count the number of elements in A whose contents are less than 10.
- Create a new array B of size 5 such that for all B[i] (0<=i<=19), B[i] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[i]

Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("This program fills an array A of size 5 with random integers in the range 1 to 100 and prints it out");
int[] arrayA;
arrayA = new int[5];
int min = 0;
int max = 100;

Random randNum = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.Length; i++)
{
    arrayA[i] = randNum.Next(min, max);
    Console.WriteLine(arrayA[i]);
}

int sum = arrayA.Sum();
Console.WriteLine("The sum of the array elements is " + sum);

int count = arrayA.Where(x => x < 10).Distinct().Count();
Console.WriteLine("The number of less than 10 value array elements is " + count);
```

I'm struggling with the last one point: does anybody have clue how to solve it ?:)

Comment: There's a contradiction in `(c)` as you have stated it. If the array `b[]` is of size 5, it cannot have indices `i` in the range `0<=i<=19`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and [mre].

Comment: I agree with You Matthew, there is a contradiction. But I'm still trying to figured it out how to make new array using integers from old array omitting this range 0<=i<=19 . Is there any code clue for that?